# Associative array (mixed data) to object properties

Tags: php, mysql, oop

The problem is not exactly passing arrays to objects per se, but distributing the initial values acquired from the database correctly in their related objects. Here's the situation. I have a forum member class and I need to pass only the values relevant to that class and also make it so it would assume certain array keys are one and the same, specifically the user ID key.

Example of a member class:

```
class Member {
    private $id;
    private $username;
    
    public function __construct($row) {
        foreach($row as $key => $value) {
            $this->$key = $value;
        }

    public function getUserURL() {
        return '<a href="profile.php?id=' . $this->id . '">' . $this->username . '</a>';
    }
}
```

Now imagine there is a posts table too and I need to get both post and user/author data from that:

```
$res = $db->query("SELECT posts.id, posts.author_id, users.username FROM posts JOIN users ON author_id = users.id");
$row = $res->fetch_assoc();
```

And now I need to inject the user data into the member class for instantiation:

```
$author = new Member($row);
```

And there goes the first problem. I'm not really injecting only the author data but also post data into it. This could be solved in a number of dubious ways. One of them is injecting the relevant values separately instead of entire array like this:

```
 $author = new Member($row["author_id"], $row["username"], ...);
```

But this isn't very convenient as there could be more to author values than just these two, plus they can vary in number and position, which means I'd have to remember their positions and sometimes fill in the gaps with empty values or **NULLs**.

Of course, I could just ignore the fact I'm passing foreign data along, memory is cheap, but you may have noticed that there is still one more problem on top of it, which is the user ID key (author_id!= id). Depending on a page/table it can be "id", "uid", "author_id", "from_id", etc. Using an alias for user/author ID in the queries isn't an option either, because sometimes I need those foreign keys to be exactly what they are as they provide more leverage to the code logic.

A potential solution to both issues could be the following:

```
$author = new Member($row["author_id"]);
$author->getUserURL($row["username"]);
```

This way I don't have to worry about either foreign data or varying user/author ID keys as all are strictly defined and just once. However, the problem with this scenario is that it makes the member class hardly useful now that most of it has to be done manually. Passing values to each method for one thing. And if previously it would use existing object properties to concoct the needed result, now they mostly just return what's already in the array. What I really want is just inject an array and do something as simple as this:

```
$author->getUserURL();
$author->getUserAvatar();
$author->getUserHomepage();
```

...etc. But it seems unachievable unless two conditions are met: 1) Fixed user ID key, 2) Strictly user data. It obviously works on profile and members pages (no foreign data), but not anywhere else. Of course, I could ignore all that foreign data in object and just use **array_key_exists()** to check for all possible variants of author/user ID like this:

```
public function __construct($row) {
    
    if(array_key_exists("author_id", $row)) {
        $this->id = $row["author_id"];
    }
    
    if(array_key_exists("from_id", $row)) {
        $this->id = $row["from_id"];
    }
    
    ...
}
```

...but this is just not elegant enough. I need a more refined approach and I can't seem to come up with one. It appears that to get it right I have to at least partially break the class or somehow split the array into posts and user data, but I don't see how this could be done without too much work. It's at times like this that I just want to run two DB queries to get two separate arrays of data out of the box, which could solve everything, but everyone knows that that, too, is a bad practice.

So, has anyone got better ideas? I do realize that this isn't the best of questions as it's mostly about efficiency and not "how", but it's small things like this that could lead to bad coding in the long run and I'm still fresh to OOP.

Comment: My solution has always been to split the query. So one query for the users table, and another for the posts table. The speed penalty for that is bearable, and you save requesting a lot of data if one user has many posts.

Comment: I'm surprised someone actually does that. I thought it's a no-go even if the impact is negligible... thank you for the input!

Comment: Don't be surprised, your whole question is an illustration of why splitting queries can make live easier. You're basically building your own [ORM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object%E2%80%93relational_mapping), and they (mostly) work like this. There will always be a need for complex queries, to get things done quickly, but often simple is better.

Comment: You question is also great illustration why using arrays instead of object is usually a PITA. I'd all I can to have just data class instead of pesky array - once you got that you do not care key order, key typos and all these things. And if you on PHP8 then you can also try my [Lombok PHP](https://github.com/MarcinOrlowski/lombok-php) to avoid writing all the boilerplate code like getters/setters.

Comment: KIKO Software, yes, I would actually spend ridiculous amounts of time building very complex queries and it's by far the most difficult part in all of my work and all because of this firm belief that I have to get the most from single database calls at all times. You have shaken this belief :)

Comment: Marcin Orlowski, I'm still on PHP 7.4, but thank you for the tip! Once I'm on PHP 8 I might check it out!